# MS Project 2010 - Create project from a set of variables

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

Being new to MS Project, I am wondering if I can create a project based on a defined template modified by some variables.

I am dealing with several (20+) projects I have to manage parallel. The projects themselves are almost identical in structure, i.e. they all have six sequential work packages that have a defined ratio of effort (e.g package 1 is 45% of the total project effort, package 2 is 5% and so on). They basically only differ in the following variables:

- Start date
- End date
- Total hours available
- Assignment of the six fixed, sequential work packages to authors (aka resources)

Is it possible in MS Project to define a project template and generate a project plan just from entering the variables listed above and have the rest (like start/end dates and hours for the individual work packages) be filled in automatically? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to save a project as a template in MS Project. You can find this feature at `File > Export > File Types > Save Project as File`.
Choose `Project Template` and save. This will lead you to a dialog where you can remove non-generic data from your project (costs, etc.) and save the template.
To load a template, click `File > New`, select your template and click `Create`.

To fill in data automatically, I'd recommend importing via Excel (`File > New > New from Excel workbook`).

Comment: To clarify there are two separate methods above: 1) With the template method, you'll just need to set a project start date (which will ripple through all tasks if they are linked property and are not otherwise constrained) and set resource availability and assign as necessary. 2)  Creating a schedule from Excel data works wonderfully but can be tricky if you don't have much experience with MS Project.